# webpack serve fails with Error: Cannot find module 'serve'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

Hi have installed the latest versions of webpack, webpack-cli, and webpack-dev-server locally and globally. Cli commands *'webpack', 'webpack info'* and *'webpack help'* works but *'webpack server'* and other commands do not:
eg: webpack info

```
% webpack info

  System:
    OS: macOS 11.6
    CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Memory: 630.58 MB / 16.00 GB
  Binaries:
    Node: 12.16.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 95.0.4638.69
    Safari: 15.1
  Packages:
    babel-loader: ^8.2.3 => 8.2.3 
    css-loader: ^6.5.0 => 6.5.0 
    eslint-import-resolver-webpack: ^0.10.1 => 0.10.1 
    file-loader: ^6.2.0 => 6.2.0 
    react-hot-loader: ^4.12.11 => 4.13.0 
    style-loader: ^3.3.1 => 3.3.1 
    webpack: ^5.61.0 => 5.61.0 
    webpack-cli: ^4.9.1 => 4.9.1 
    webpack-dev-middleware: ^5.2.1 => 5.2.1 
    webpack-dev-server: ^4.4.0 => 4.4.0 
    webpack-hot-middleware: ^2.25.1 => 2.25.1 
  Global Packages:
    webpack-cli: 4.9.1
    webpack-dev-server: 4.4.0
    webpack: 5.61.0
```

eg: webpack serve

```
% webpack serve
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/<uname>/Projects/react/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'serve'
Require stack:
- /Users/<uname>/Projects/react/webpack.config.js
- /Users/<uname>/Projects/react/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /Users/<uname>/Projects/react/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /Users/<uname>/Projects/react/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/import-local/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<uname>/Projects/react/webpack.config.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/<uname>/Projects/react/webpack.config.js',
    '/Users/<uname>/Projects/react/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/Users/<uname>/Projects/react/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/Users/<uname>/Projects/react/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules/import-local/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

Can someone help me?

UPDATE: Here is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
let config = require('./config')

if (process.argv[2]) {
  config = require(`${process.argv[2]}`)
}
module.exports = {
  entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', './src/index.jsx'],
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-flow"],
            plugins: [
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
              "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
              "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
              "react-hot-loader/babel",
              "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
            ]
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    fallback: {
      "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
      "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
      "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
    },
    fullySpecified: false,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(), new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.HOST_URL': `"${config.host}"`
  })]
}
```

Comment: `Failed to load '/Users/<uname>/Projects/react/webpack.config.js' config`
Post your config. It's probably messed up (:

Comment: @nlta updated my webpack config in the post

Comment: Try `./node_modules/.bin/webpack serve` ?

Comment: No luck I get the same error